# See python error console in blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting

When running a python file in blender 2.8, I get the message *Python script fail, look in the console for now*. According to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97976/python-script-fail-look-in-the-console-for-now), I should be able to see the error in Window > Toggle System Console. However my window dropdown menu doesn't have a Toggle System Console button. How am I able to see the error messages?

I am on macOS High Sierra and have blender 2.80.

here is a picture of my window menu:
[image: window menu]

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your window dropdown and add it to the question please?

Comment: Sure, i just did @WhatAMesh

Comment: Have a look at: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102860/how-to-open-system-console-to-get-output-from-blender-on-mac-os-10

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found my answer in there. Is there a way to mark a question as solved without an answer?

Comment: @person132: if the individual who offered the answer doesn't respond, you can write your own answer and credit them in the text.  Then mark your answer "accepted"